# no name "object property" in module kivy.properties pylint no name in module

Tags: python, kivy

when i try from kivy.prperties import NumericProperty,ReferenceListProperty, ObjectProperty
i was shown No name "Numeric Property" in module kivy.properties pylintno no name in module. Using visual studio code. is that happens because vs code could not read cython libraries if so how to rectify it?

Comment: Please post your codes.

Comment: This seems to be a problem with pylint. See https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/6583. For now, I just disable the warning with this line of code:
    # pylint: disable=no-name-in-module